# Best practices for performance benchmarking test

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, benchmarking

I have a J2EE web-application running on Sun hardware with `OpenSolaris/Glassfish` stack. We're starting our performance bench-marking tests, to prepare for our scalability requirements later.

Any guidelines/best practices would be very useful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is many generic ways to test server performance to be found on the web.

But have you thought that perhaps this an opportunity to gather [stories](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/userstories.html) and write a test tuned to exactly how your users will use the server? Even if it doesn't perfectly reflect the way that the server will ultimately work, it will let you start learning something rather than being only formal exercise. I think this is the spirit of [agile development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development).

Answer (score 1):

For a free Open Source tool I've found Apache's Jmeter pretty good:
http://jmeter.apache.org/

As Joe said you'll need to figure out how to model user behaviour and simulate user load.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JUnit? For simple Time Measurement in JUnit there is [JUnitPerf](http://clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html) which also supports LoadTests. JUnit 4 is not supported very well but it works for me. ContiPerf is an alternative which also supports annotations for easy configuration. I use this before using JMeter.